# Autofac register open generic types defined in external referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, generics, autofac

I am experiencing problems with Autofac when trying to register "automatically" all closed implementations of some open generic type, if these are defined in referenced assemblies.
If everything is defined in the main assembly, all works fine.

```
Assembly mainExecAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
List<Assembly> assemblies= new List<Assembly>();
assemblies.Add(mainExecAssembly);
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies.ToArray())
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IMyOpenGenericTypeHandler<>))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

But if these are defined in referenced assemblies (which are iterated and loaded at bootstrap):

```
Assembly mainExecAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
List<Assembly> assemblies= new List<Assembly>();
assemblies.Add(mainExecAssembly);
AssemblyName[] aNames = mainExecAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
foreach (var an in aNames)
{
    Assembly a = Assembly.Load(an.FullName);
    assemblies.Add(a);
}
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies.ToArray())
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IMyOpenGenericTypeHandler<>))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

then the concrete implementation of the open generic type is not registered.

The concrete types look like this:

```
public class MyExtendedTypeHandler: IMyOpenGenericTypeHandler<MyExtendedType>
{
    public MyExtendedTypeHandler()
    {
    }
    public void Handle(MyExtendedType handle)
    {
    }
}

public interface IMyOpenGenericTypeHandler<T> where T: IMyT
{
    void Handle(T handle);
}

public interface IMyT
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyType: IMyT
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyExtendedType: MyType
{
    public string Name { get; internal set; }

    public MyExtendedType(string name)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `assemblies` variable contains the requested assembly ?

Comment: Actually the interfaces definitions and the concrete types implementing the interfaces are in two different external assemblies, and this seems to be the problem. If the definitions of the interfaces and the classes implementing the generic interfaces are in the same (external) assembly, it works. How could this problem be solved ?

Comment: I try to reproduce the issue with a console application that register things in Autofac, this application reference an assembly that contains the 2 interfaces and another assembly that contains the 3 classes. The registration seems to work. Could you update your question with information on who reference who and which assemblies contains which type ?

Comment: I have checked my code and found indeed that an interface was defined twice in 2 different namespaces, and that lead to the problems. After fixing that, Autofac registers all classes that implement the interface, also from external assemblies. Thank you for the support.